# xPath Groupings how?

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa, xpath

OK So, I'm learning/using xpath for a basic application that's effectively ripping data off another website.

I need to gain the knowledge of each persons Country/Suburb/area.
In some instances you can get Australia/Victoria/Melbourne for instance.
Others may just be Australia/Melbourne.
Or even just Melbourne OR just Australia.

So I'm current able to view the below code and rip all of the information with the string xpath `//table/tr/td/table/tr/td/font/a`. This returns every entry, but what I really want is to group each lot separately.

I hope someone out there on planet earth knows what I just tried to explain... and can help...

Good day!

The source document contains data like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <font face="arial" size="2">  
            <strong>Location:</strong>
            <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Australia" target="mapblast" style="text-decoration:none">Australia</a>,
            <a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Australia%20Victoria'target="mapblast" style='text-decoration:none'>Victoria</a>, 
            <a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Australia%20Melbourne%20Victoria'target="mapblast" style='text-decoration:none'>Melbourne</a>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'd like to comment on the fact you are using XML with an HTML document. I cannot see the entire document so cannot determine if you are using XHTML. If you are using HTML here, you might run into issues loading your HTML files as they could be 'non well-formed' XML.

2nd comment i'd like to make is that you are using the "//" to start your XPath query. This means "All nodes in the document". Given your requirements, i think a "//td/font/a" would suffice. Not using the '//' all together is the best performand option.

Answer (score 1):

To find each person's record, the XPath query is `//table/tr/td/table/tr/td/font`, or you could use `//td/font[strong = 'Location:']`. This will return a collection containing 1 element for each person.

To find the `a` elements under a particular `font` you could use XPath `a` from the `font`. This can also be done by iterating the children collection of the element.